# When pronouncing variable-names-like-this, why do all programmers say dash instead of hyphen?

Tags: naming-conventions

After doing some research, I believe these are hyphens, not dashes. However all programmers I met say dashes. Is there a reason? If I keep saying hyphen hyphen hyphen, would I sound weird?

Comment: They _are_ hyphens, in fact. However, early programming languages didn't allow hyphens as part of an identifier (most languages nowadays still don't allow them), so we programmers used dashes instead. And probabily we took to calling them "dashes" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because it’s easier to say. “Dash dash dash” vs. “hyphen hyphen hyphen”. One of those is a mouthful.

Same as saying “dot” instead of “period” in URLs and IPs.

Comment: Also, I've noted some tech types I know who say "dub dub dub" rather than double-you double-you double-you" when giving a URL.